# Boolean Identity: (x + yx) = (x + y)(x + z) what is z

Tags: boolean-algebra

In the boolean Identity:

> (x + yx) = (x + y)(x + z)

Where does z come from and what does it mean?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the exercise - should be rather $(x + yz) = (x + y)(x + z).$

Comment: It would have to be a typo in my text book 'Computer System Architecture 3e' - Mano. See(https://imgur.com/Vg8XKdw) identity 14. I've seen the same identity elsewhere on the web too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be $$X+YZ=(X+Y)(X+Z)$$.
Please check your question once again.
Or see the link

https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/meesh/webpages/old-cmsc311/HW/chap2.text

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please upvote this answer.

Comment: I added the image of the identity to a comment under my question.

Answer (score 0):

$x=0, 1=>x^2=x=>$
$$
\\x+xy=x^2+xy=x(x+y)=(x+0)(x+y)
$$ 
$=>z=0$